# Powershell scripts: Create user profile synchronization service using sharepoint active directory

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, user-profile, sharepoint-2013

In sharepoint 2013 I have to create user profile synchronization connection using sharepoint active directory through scripts. I have created the user profile service using powershell after that is there any way to select the option in Configure Synchronization Settings to select Use SharePoint Active Directory in Synchronization Options. After that I have to create the synchronization connection using scripts.

I have scripts for sharepoint 2010 but I could't find scripts for sharepoint 2013. If anyone have tried this before please help me out

Thank You

---

thanks selecting that option working fine.. but i couldn't create a connection after that this is code i used to create a connection

Add-SPProfileSyncConnection -ProfileServiceApplication 53eb09e7-4269-4e88-9109-ea29f603043a

-ConnectionForestName "abcde.com"

-ConnectionDomain "abcde"

-ConnectionUserName "username"

-ConnectionPassword "password" -asplaintext -force

-ConnectionSynchronizationOU "OU=abc,DC=abcde,DC=com"

this script is giving the following error

Add-SPProfileSyncConnection : Can not get to the proxy. Please verify that the
proxy is running.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-SPProfileSyncConnection
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Offic...eSyncConnection:
   SPCmdletAddProfileSyncConnection) [Add-SPProfileSyncConnection], ArgumentE
  xception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PowerShell.
   SPCmdletAddProfileSyncConnection

for -ConnectionSynchronizationOU am i giving the correct parameters?? can you help me on this??

Answer (score 1):

This is from my blog at 
http://www.benjaminathawes.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=42

$upa=Get-SPServiceApplication -Name "UserProfileServiceAppName"

$upa.NoILMUsed=$true

$upa.Update()

I also suggest you check out Spence's article on AD Direct Import here:
http://www.harbar.net/archive/2012/07/23/sp13adi.aspx